# Trying to load a lot of <video> tags on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I am loading a lot of videos onto a page with the video tag. The issue is that it takes a long time for all of the videos to load and if you are trying to load a specific video it may wait for others to load before it because there are so many.

My solution is to load the thumbnail of all of these videos on the page and when you click on the thumbnail have it switch to the video and load the video.

I am not sure how I should go about doing thing. I was going to use jQuery and when a user clicks the image make the video visible but I am not sure if when a video is set to hidden will it still try to load?

What is the best way to display a video with the video tag after a user clicks on an image with jQuery?

Comment: use the video's poster attrib, no js needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, browsers do load resources inside elements that are hidden by CSS, so that they can be un-hidden quickly. If you want to load only on command, you probably need to build the  element dynamically and add it to the page only when needed. Something like:

```
var video = $("<video/>"); 
video.append($("<source/>").attr("src", "video.mp4").attr("type", "video/mp4");
$("#placeholder").html(video);
```

The easiest way to extend this to multiple videos would be to place the video URL as data on each of your images with the [jQuery .data() method](http://api.jquery.com/data/), and load the appropriate video URL from the image's data in one universal click handler.

Answer (score 2):

Here was what I came up with thanks to interfect's answer.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".thumb").click(function() {
        var value;
        value = $(this).data("video");
        $(this).replaceWith('<video src="'+value+'" controls autoplay></video>');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 already supports a thumbnail preview using the poster attribute without jQuery. No need to hide the video. e.g.

```
<video height="200" width="480" poster="http://somesite.com/thumbs/pathtoimage.jpg" preload="none" controls>
    <source src="http://somesite.com/pathto.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <p class="warning">Your browser does not support HTML5 video.</p>
</video>
```

If you have a lot of videos, then might suggest loading them with ajax as needed  or as the user scrolls etc.

Comment: I know I can use a poster, that is irrelevant I am really just looking to load a video as an image is clicked

Comment: What I read sounded different. _"I am not sure how I should go about doing thing. I was going to use jQuery and when a user clicks the image make the video visible"_. So I was answering that, meaning the video doesn't need to be made visible because the thumbnail poster will be there and you can just click it, don't need to hide it. Maybe make your question a bit clearer.